# How to re-open app from the page the app was backed out from?

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to get my app to re-open to a 'home' view of sorts, after the user backs out of the app to the device screen. The intent is to keep them from going back to the login screen once they have logged in (when, say, they just start backing out of the app), and launching the 'home' (logged in) view when they re-open the app after backing out of it.

When the app starts, it sends the user to a 'loading' view, where the app checks auth status. Once status is obtained, it transfers them to either a 'login' view or a 'logged in' view. Once a user logs in, I don't want them to be able to go back to the login view, or the 'loading' view, so I implemented `clearHistory` when navigating from the 'loading' or the 'login' view to the 'logged in' view.

The problem, is when I tap the device back button while in the 'logged in' view, it will back out of the app to the device as intended. However, when I open the app back up from either the app icon or the 'recent screens' (android), it will open the app again, but displays the 'loading' view. Only this time it will not actually do anything, which isn't really the issue. Again it's the fact that this view is showing in the first place.

Here's my 'loading' view navigation code:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");

var home_navigation = {
  moduleName: "views/home/home",
  clearHistory: true
};

if(logged){
  var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
  topmost.navigate(home_navigation);
}

else {
  var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
  topmost.navigate(splash_navigation);
}
```

For the login page, `clearHistory` is also used when navigating to the home page on login.

From my understanding, the entire history should clear upon navigating, leaving the view navigated to as the only history entry. So when a user taps back, it should go directly from that last view (home) to the device screen (which it does), and open that view when the user re-opens the app (which it doesn't). Any advice here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

On your *app.ts (or .js)* you need some way to check if the user has been auth'd prior to calling the `application.start()`.

When a user logs into your app, store some key indicating this using the *application-settings* module.

`import * as appSettings from 'application-settings';
let yourKey = 'whatever';
appSettings.setString('userAuthed', yourKey);`

On the app.ts (.js) file

```
    import * as app from 'application';
    import * as appSettings from 'application-settings'

    let userAuthed = appSettings.getString('userAuthed');
    let x = JSON.parse(userAuthed) /// assuming you stringify some object and store it
    if (x.name && x.isValid) {
       app.start(''' your main page ''')
    } else {
       app.start(''' login page ''');
    }
```